# Accurately track the play count of SoundCloud songs played through custom SoundManager2 player

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud, soundmanager2

Much like this question ( [List tracks from Soundcloud and play it with Soundmanager 2 on a Wordpress blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464400/list-tracks-from-soundcloud-and-play-it-with-soundmanager-2-on-a-wordpress-blog) ) we also use SoundManager2 to play Mp3s from SoundCloud and it we already have it working and receive the JSON query. My question is: when we play these songs through our custom player; is there a way to have the play count increase on the actual SoundCloud page? We need for the artists to be able to track the increased play counts that we bring in if possible.

Answer (score 1):

i think that play count increases wherever you play the track. at least, it works for flash embed player, but not sure about the sm2 player, nor html5 player. i hope it works too. if not, it should.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm this is correct. We use the Sound Manager library on the HTML5 widget (when it's needed). The play counts are managed for you when the stream is played, regardless of what's actually playing it. If you don't see the stats increase, that might just be a delay in propagating the counts across the servers.