# get correct .mp3 url from soundcloud api for use with soundmanager2 360-player

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, soundmanager2

My question is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464400/list-tracks-from-soundcloud-and-play-it-with-soundmanager-2-on-a-wordpress-blog#comment15797049_9386528) one here, however as the question was never resolved and I can't message PeeHaa privately to ask the answer I'll ask again here.

I've successfully queried the soundcloud api and gotten my the stream_url for each track and added it to all the hrefs of my 360 player [(demo here)](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/). My code for the elements looks something like this:

```
<div class="ui360">
 <a href="/path/to/an.mp3" data-title="Track title">play "an.mp3"</a>
</div>
```

I have this script to find all the a tags with data-title attributes and give them the correct href based on the stream_url, but when I try to click the soundmanager icon in the browser and play the track, it just gets redirected to the .mp3 url.

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});

SC.get('/playlists/2450655', 'allow_redirects=False', function(playlist) {

  var titles = $('.audio .ui360 a').each(function(index){
    this.index = index;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < playlist.tracks.length; i++) {    
    var id = '?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'    
    for (var j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {      
      if (playlist.tracks[i].title === $(titles[j]).attr('data-title')) {
        $(titles[j]).attr('href', playlist.tracks[i].stream_url+id)
      }            
    }    
  }

});
```

Does anyone know how to get the correct url for playing tracks hosted on soundcloud in this manner?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but the problem was driving me up the wall and I finally figured it out, so here's my answer for others:

Soundmanager will work if you specify an mp3 mimetype in the link:

```
<div class="ui360">
    <a type="audio/mp3" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49349198/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" data-title="Track title">play "an.mp3"</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK to stream the tracks? Something like:

```
SC.get('/playlists/2450655', function(playlist) {
  $(playlist.tracks).each(function(index, track) {
    $('a[href="' + track.stream_url + '"]').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id, function(sound) {
         sound.play();
       });
    });
  });
});
```

Would that solve your problem, or is there a particular reason you need to resolve the URL?

Comment: Yea I got that working successfully. The reason I want to do it this way is to use the 360-player. http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/